# R: Time-Series Measurements of Multiple Sensors with Missing Observations (Mice? Sensor-Fusion)

Tags: r, r-mice, sensor-fusion

This is probably a very common sensor-fusion problem.

I have a set of (temperature) sensors that are all trying to measure the same thing.  They may be offset by a constant, with or without noise.  Alas, the sensors didn't work at random times, and moreover some were installed, some were removed.  a simple example with three sensors would be:

```
x1 <- c(rnorm(11)); x2 <- x1 + 10; x3 <- x2 + 50
x1[1:4] <- NA; x2[3:8] <- NA; x3[7:10] <- NA
x1[11] <- x2[11] <- x3[11] <- NA
```

This gives me an availability pattern of:

```
# 12345678901
# ....YYYYYY.
# YY......YY.
# YYYYYY.....
```

What I must absolutely avoid is the predictable changes when a sensor comes on-line or off-line, so `rowMeans` over available sensors is terrible.

In this example without noise, I could even perfectly infer the missing values.  Perfect collinearity is my friend.  Here, I could use obs 1+2 to infer x1 (from x2 and x3), 5+6 to infer x2; and 9+10 to infer x3.  now I have cases with all three sensors, which I can use to infer even 3+4 and 7+8, even though I only have one sensor working.  Finally, I can take the `rowMeans`, and I have everything from 1:10, and, important, an NA in 11.  More generally, I would have to try different subsets of variables and observations and then fill in iteratively.

I cannot work with complete.cases (no such thing), and I do not want `mice` to make time-series interpolations.  however, I still want `mice` like intelligent iterations to create reasonably consistent cross-sensor fitted values, over which I can later take the rowMeans.  I could start with observations that have the most sensor observations, work my way up, and then do a rowMeans or a factor analysis.  (`mice` could help if it has a parameter to suppress its attempts to do time-series interpolation.  does it?)

However, it would be better to recognize that measured values are more reliable than fitted values.

Pointers to solutions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like there aren't enough constraints here to solve for an answer.  Do you have some sense of priors around what a reasonable value is? In your example, the variation between sensors is ~30x the variation within sensors, so what would a reasonable answer look like?

Comment: any time-series that has the time-series variation of the original x1 (before it was partly wiped out) up to any constant.  An equal-weighted average would be fine, as would be x1 or x3.  I need to know when temperature is going up and going down, not exactly what temperature is.

Comment: perhaps then you should look at the average non-NA change at each time.

Comment: that would have huge jumps when a sensor comes off-line or on-line.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this solves your problem, but it gives me the result I'd expect from the data, identifying the typical change from point to point among the available observations.

```
library(tidyverse)
# using set.seed(42) before generating data
data.frame(x1, x2, x3) |>
  mutate(time = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-time) |>
  mutate(chg = value - lag(value), .by = name) |>
  summarize(chg_median = median(chg, na.rm = TRUE), .by = time)
```

Result

```
    time chg_median
   <int>      <dbl>
 1     1     NA    
 2     2     -1.94 
 3     3      0.928
 4     4      0.270
 5     5     -0.229
 6     6     -0.510
 7     7      1.62 
 8     8     -1.61 
 9     9      2.11 
10    10     -2.08 
11    11     NA
```

Visual check

```
df |> # df = result of chain up to `mutate(chg`...
  ggplot(aes(time, value)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = name)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = name)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = time - 0.5, xend = time -0.5, y = 0, yend = chg_median),
               arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(5, "points")),
               data = df |> 
                 summarize(chg_median = median(chg, na.rm = TRUE), .by = time))
```

[image]

Comment: working with changes to begin with is indeed probably the most obvious solution --- once suggested.  the emperor's new clothes.  thanks, jon